# Is it possible to ignore SIGHUP in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nohup

I want to create a Ruby script, which will start like this:

```
$ ruby script.rb &
```

Then, I will close the console and it must stay alive, working in the background. At the moment I have to run it like this, in order to achive that:

```
$ nohup ruby script.rb &
```

I want to get rid of `nohup` and deal with [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) directly inside the script -- simply ignore it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just [`Signal.trap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Signal.html#method-c-trap) `HUP` signal:

```
def do_fork
  $pid = fork do
    Signal.trap("HUP") do
      puts "Received HUP, ignoring..."
    end
    Signal.trap("TERM") do
      puts "Received TERM, terminating..."
      exit(0)
    end
    while true do sleep(10_000) end
  end

  Process.detach($pid)
end

do_fork
```

Copy the code above to some file and run it with `ruby file.rb` to see it ignores `kill -HUP pid` and closes on `kill -TERM pid`.

Comment: I just did, it immediately exits. Are you sure the script is correct and doesn't need something like `Process.wait` at the end?

Comment: I am sure. Check your process list, it should be still there.

Comment: You are right! What is the point of wrapping it all in a function? Can't we get rid of `do_fork` and do it all right in the script?

Comment: We can, that way it is more reliable for future modifications. If you are fine with that simple functionality, get rid of the function.